# Fill between 2 lines that are behind the candlestick bars on the plot in plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am using plotly to plot.  The dataframe contains OHLC data, which are plotted as candlesticks.  Additionally, it has moving averages, which are plotted as scatter line types.  From those MAs, I calculate zones using pandas.  I would like to plot those zones on the chart as well.  But I need the zones to be behind the candlesticks and MA lines.

Here is a sample data with a zone:

```
Date         Time        Open    High    Low     Close   ZoneBot    ZoneTop
1/3/2021    22:01:00    1.77089 1.77126 1.77089 1.77126 1.772686    1.773486
1/3/2021    22:02:00    1.77141 1.77141 1.77126 1.77126 1.772704    1.773504
1/3/2021    22:03:00    1.77112 1.77146 1.77112 1.77136 1.772726    1.773526
1/3/2021    22:04:00    1.77121 1.77277 1.77114 1.77127 1.772747    1.773547
1/3/2021    22:05:00    1.7711  1.77132 1.77094 1.77094 1.772768    1.773568
1/3/2021    22:06:00    1.77117 1.77117 1.77052 1.77052 1.772784    1.773584
1/3/2021    22:07:00    1.77086 1.77086 1.7706  1.77083 1.772796    1.773596
1/3/2021    22:08:00    1.77088 1.77088 1.77086 1.77086 1.772811    1.773611
1/3/2021    22:09:00    1.77084 1.77084 1.77071 1.77071 1.772826    1.773626
1/3/2021    22:10:00    1.7707  1.77084 1.77064 1.77064 1.772839    1.773639
```

I have tried creating traces and filling between them.  But fill is on top of everything else.  The candles and MAs are not visible anymore.

I understand you cannot set the order of traces like in matplotlib or mplfinance; I saw the request already submitted for zorder on github.

So I was thinking I could try drawing a shape, because the shape you can set to go behind the traces.

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't plot anything:

```
# create a path shape that follows the curve of the line
    path_commands = f'M{df.index[0],df[f"ZoneBot"][0]} '
    for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
        path_commands += f'L{df.index[i],df[f"ZoneBot"][i]} '
    for i in range(len(df.index)-1, -1, -1):
        path_commands += f'L{df.index[i],df[f"ZoneTop"][i]} '
    path_commands += f'Z'

    figure.add_shape(type='path',
                  path=path_commands,
                  fillcolor='black',
                  line=dict(color='black'),
                  opacity=0.5,
                  xref='x',
                  yref='y')
```

I also thought I could use rectangles for each data point.  The problem with this is it took way to long to render.  If there are 100 data points. That is 100 shapes per zone being rendered.  Here is an example of that code:

```
for i in range(1,len(df.index)-1):
        figure.add_shape(type="rect",
        x0=df.index[i], x1=df.index[i+1], y0=df[f'ZoneBot'].iloc[i], 
        y1=df[f'ZoneTop'].iloc[i+1],fillcolor='black',
        line=dict(color='black'),)
```

I request guidance as I am not able to find a solution by googling or figuring it out myself.

Comment: Is your intention something similar to this [example](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes)? Do you want to replace the line chart with a candlestick and draw more of a rectangular background?

Comment: No.  It is more like filling an area between two MA lines.  It looks like this: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oiblcPrzM8g/VRMgFJg2aWI/AAAAAAAAAgI/d4rYYjxXITI/s1600/Band%2Bchart.gif.   Why I said rectangle was drawing a rectangle for one bar between the two MA line.  If you do this 100 times, then it "appears" a  fill between 2 lines.  But it is too many shapes to do that way.

Comment: Then the area graph is the best choice. An example can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/#overlaid-area-chart-without-boundary-lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is what @Derek O said plus to use color="rgba(255,0,0,0.1)"

The last float is the alpha channel (which is opacity).  By doing this, it allows you to select your own fill color, set the correct opacity, and still see the candlesticks.

Answer (score 1):

As @r-beginners mentioned, an area graph might be your best choice. This would allow you to plot the moving averages (zone bottom and zone top) as two additional traces, which should be less computationally expensive than rendering shapes for every pair of consecutive points.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

csv_string = StringIO("""Date         Time        Open    High    Low     Close   ZoneBot    ZoneTop
1/3/2021    22:01:00    1.77089 1.77126 1.77089 1.77126 1.772686    1.773486
1/3/2021    22:02:00    1.77141 1.77141 1.77126 1.77126 1.772704    1.773504
1/3/2021    22:03:00    1.77112 1.77146 1.77112 1.77136 1.772726    1.773526
1/3/2021    22:04:00    1.77121 1.77277 1.77114 1.77127 1.772747    1.773547
1/3/2021    22:05:00    1.7711  1.77132 1.77094 1.77094 1.772768    1.773568
1/3/2021    22:06:00    1.77117 1.77117 1.77052 1.77052 1.772784    1.773584
1/3/2021    22:07:00    1.77086 1.77086 1.7706  1.77083 1.772796    1.773596
1/3/2021    22:08:00    1.77088 1.77088 1.77086 1.77086 1.772811    1.773611
1/3/2021    22:09:00    1.77084 1.77084 1.77071 1.77071 1.772826    1.773626
1/3/2021    22:10:00    1.7707  1.77084 1.77064 1.77064 1.772839    1.773639""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_string, sep="\s+")
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'], y=df['ZoneBot'], name='Zone Bottom')) # no fill from bottom trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'], y=df['ZoneTop'], name='Zone Top', fill='tonexty')) # fill to trace0 y

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df['DateTime'],
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close']))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Derek, I copied your code, and it worked.  The difference between your's and what I tried before, is I entered a value for "fillcolor."  As soon as I do that, then the area shape becomes opaque, and you cannot see the other traces.  I have tried to play with opacity, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  How can I change the color to something other than default and still be able to see the candles behind the area shape like I can with the default?

Comment: @JonathanStearns I think you should be able to see the candles if you add those after the area plot – i've updated my code

Comment: Good idea.  My orignal go.Figure() had the candle stick trace and a few moving average traces.  then, I added traces for the zones, like your suggestion.  I switched those.  I added the zones into the go.Figure first.  Then, I added the candlestick and moving average traces.  You were correct in that the moving averages were now on top of the zones.  But the candlesticks were still behind the zones. I put the candlestick trace last.  Last thing I tried, I pulled the candlesticks outside go.Figure() and added candlesticks with figure.add_trace().  Still behind the zones.

Comment: I read the documentation on candlesticks in ploty.  It said the candle increasing and decreasing color is a variant of transulent of another color.  So I specified a color for increasing and decreasing to make it opaque.  But did not any affect.

Comment: Instead of go.Figure() and add_trace, I tried make_subplots() and add_trace().  It did not fix it.